# Task Exception Handling without Wait

Tags: c#, exception, task

When working with Tasks, I am not sure how to do handling when I do not call Wait on my task.  The example below is not executed in an async method.

Here is an example:

```
var t = Task.Run(() =>
{
  // do something as part of the task concurrently
});
```

Would wrapping the entire block above and catching Exception be correct way?

I know I can Wait for the task result like below and handle exception but my question is related to above block without call to t.Wait.

```
try
{
  t.Wait();  
}
catch(AggregateException ae)
{
  // handle exception(s)
}
```

So, my question is whether this is correct way to handle exception when I don't Wait (or await) for task?

```
try
{
  var t = Task.Run(() =>
  {
    // do something as part of the task concurrently
  });
}
catch(Exception ex) //NOTE general Exception
{
  // show exception in message box or log it somewhere
}
```

**UPDATE1**
, or should I do it like this?

```
  var t = Task.Run(
      () => 
      {
        try
        {
          // do something as part of the task concurrently
        }
        catch(Exception ex) //NOTE general Exception
        {
          // show exception in message box or log it somewhere
        }
       });
```

Comment: Nit pick on your word choice, "*// do something as part of the task asynchronously*" should be "*// do something as part of the task **concurrently***". Using `Task.Run` does not make somthing async, you need API support to actually be async.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Changed and updated question also to clarify what I am asking and to fix code I provided initially.

Comment: To your latest update, no it is not corect. Think about it, if you don't  wait for `t` and it takes "10 lines of code worth of time" to throw a exception you are now out of the try block.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  I added UPDATE1 above.  Is that what you are suggesting?  Thanks

Comment: Re: Update 1 - you can do that, of course. This means that your error handling is inside the task, meaning it isn't aware of being a task or of the context in which the task is run. If that's what you're after, go for it. It's no different than exception handling in any other method.

Comment: But then answer the question - should all methods handle their own exceptions, or should they throw an exception to their caller. If the latter, you need one of the solutions in the answer below.l

Comment: Your update1 is wrong too, the try needs to be after the `() => ` not before.

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code you've supplied (after the edit) won't help you in handling errors thrown *inside* your task. It will only catch exceptions thrown in the main code block, such as in scheduling the task or getting the parameters to pass to it.

#### Async/Await to simplify asynchronous task control flow

If you're using C# 5 and above (bundled with VS2013), the simplest way is to use `async/await`, which simplifies control flow for asynchronous tasks:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        DoSyncWork();
        await Task.Run(() => AsyncStuff());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {  
        // handle.
    }
}
```

The compiler will automatically deconstruct the async task and return the exception to the normal `catch` block - regardless of whether the synchronous or async parts of the code threw the exception.

#### OnlyOnFaulted continuations to handle task exceptions

If you're not using C# 5, or prefer not to use async/await (because you're handling parallelism, not just asynchrony), the technique is to use `Task.ContinueWith` to specify a continuation in case of error:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => Whatever())
               .ContinueWith(failedTask => HandleError(failedTask), 
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

This will cause the continuation to launch after the original task completes, but only if it threw an exception. You can use this to specify several continuation branches based on the result:

```
var baseTask = Task.Run(() => Whatever());            
baseTask.ContinueWith(failedTask => HandleError(failedTask), 
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
baseTask.ContinueWith(successfulTask => HandleResults(successfulTask), 
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Comment: But I don't want method DoSomething() to be an async method.  And I don't want to use await or Wait.  I updated my question code to clarify

Comment: @dbnex14 Then use the contunue with or put the try/catch inside the Task.Run instead of outside of it.

Comment: @dbnex14 Then read on to the second part of the answer. I've added section headers to clarify.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, I added UPDATE1 above.  Is that what you are suggesting with "... put the try/catch inside the Task.Run instead of outside of it."?  Thanks again

Comment: @dbnex14 As I said in the comments to the answer, this will mean that your Task will *always* complete successfully, regardless of whether it actually failed or not. The task's caller has no way of knowing which.

Answer (score 3):

Running a task inside a try/catch block will never catch exceptions if it is not awaited. The task starts on its own thread separate from the try/catch logic, so the calling part of the program continues unless it is instructed to wait for the task to finish.

If you want it to log or handle errors, build that logic into the task itself.